# Angular Workpace - can't build project without having to build other projects in same workspace

Tags: angular, angular-cli, tsconfig, ng-packagr

I have an Angular CLI workspace created with createApplcation=false.

I have 2 libraries:

```
@scope/lib1
@scope/lib2
```

lib2 has a dependency on lib1.

I have to build lib1 so that dist/lib1 is created and angular CLI knows about the package. From a CI/CD perspective, this means that every time lib2 is built, I need to build lib1.

Is this a correct assumption?
If so, is there any way to build lib2 without having to build lib1?

The example I have above is a small example but my current workspace has a lot of these intern-library dependencies in a single workspace (~12 packages). Seems pretty intensive to have to keep building upstream libraries to build downstream libraries.

Because it is a large project, I don't want to build the entire workspace every time (e.g. i have a small scss change in one of the apps and now my CI tool has to build all the upstream dependencies for this single change).

I've tried a few things:

1. add lib1 as a peerDependency in the package.json of lib2

    - Doesn't seem to do anything when the root package.json is built - as I understand it, the library's package.json is meant only for distribution metadata, not for build metadata

2. I've tried to import the module from lib1 into lib2 like `import <module> from 'projects/lib1/src/public_api` but keep getting the following error:

    `Error: error TS6059: File 'example.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/workspace/projects/lib2/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.`

FYI: using @angular/cli ~8.3 with @angular ~8.2

Comment: Hmm, old question... But you should be able to solve this using [NX](https://nx.dev). I'm looking if it would be possible in an angular workspace, but in like 2 years I haven't been successful